# Validate Company Names

Tags: python, machine-learning, geolocation, web-crawler, data-extraction

I have bunch of company names and their addresses. I want to validate them. Some of the company names are not accurate.(Misspelled, Abbreviated etc ).

To get the right company names, I have built a Google search crawler which extracts first search results when given a query. So basically when I search for a company name in google, I’m getting (most of the times) company's accurate title and URL.

Is there any other way to get right names from inaccurate company names ? Sometimes, 1st search result doesn’t take you in right direction and number of requests to call Google API are limited. How to address this problem ? Can I use Machine Learning if I gather data which somehow predicts right company name or top 5 with confidence scores ?

Comment: As Google has full data on each company it will be extremely precise if you put both company name and address into search query.

Comment: Some of the addresses are invalid. I need to validate addresses as well. Right now I'm querying company name and country  in google search.

Answer (score 0):

The notion of exact company name is very relative, the only official name is the legal name which is the one registered in the country of the company, but it's generally not the name used in the public (Who is calling Apple "Apple Inc." ?).

If you're looking at listed companies, you can then take the name used in the stock market as your reference.

For example for american stocks the SEC provides a [list](https://www.sec.gov/rules/other/4-460list.htm#a).
Some data providers will also provide this, including non-US stocks, such as yahoo finance [python module if you use python](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/), or Quandl.

If the companies you're looking at are not listed, you will probably need to scrape some website like the ones of registry offices or other business lists.

Once you have established your reference name, you can use some string matching like [Fuzzy Wuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) to map the names you have to the reference you chose.